# Objective C - nested messages ... confusion about

Tags: objective-c, syntax, semantics, message-passing

Wonder if anyone could shed some light on this messaging construct:

The documentation says that messages appear btwn brackets [] and
that the msg target/object is on the left, whilst the msg itself (and any parameters) is on the right:

[msgTarget msg], e.g., `[myArray insertObject:anObject atIndex:0]`

OK, simple enough... but then they introduce the idea that it's convenient to nest msgs in lieu of the use of temporary variables--I'll take their word for it--so the above example becomes:

`[[myAppObject theArray] insertObject:[myAppObject objectToInsert] atIndex:0]`

In other words, `[myAppObject theArray]`  is a nested msg, one, and, two, 'theArray' is the 'message'.  Well, to say I find this confusing is a bit of an understatement ... Maybe it's just me but 'theArray' doesn't evoke a message semantically or grammatically.  What this looks like to a guy who knows Java is a type/class.  In Java we do things like

`Class objectInstance = new Class() ...`

the bit to the left of the assignment operator is what this so-called nested message reminds me of ... with object and class/type positions switched of course.  Anyway, any insight much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Objective-C, by convention, you refer to properties with dot notation. Thus, you write `myAppObject.theArray` instead `[myAppObject theArray]`.

In Objective-C the default getter is the name of the variable instead `getVariable`. For example, writing

```
@property NSArray *theArray;
```

creates an instance variable `_theArray` and generates the following accessor:

```
-(NSArray*) theArray { return _theArray; }
```

So by sending `theArray` as a message you are actually invoking a method. But again, use only dot notation for properties.

Comment: OK -- got it.  Thanks very much!  I would upvote you, but I'm new around here and apparently haven't yet earned the right.